# Insert multiple rows into table and getting the values of 3 different tables

Tags: sql, insert, row

I have 4 different tables

- account,
- branch,
- tblbillers,
- tblbillerpolicy,

The 4 tables containing their columns

- account (accntID)Primary Key...
- branch (branchID)Primary KEY...
- tblbillers (Billerid) and
- tblbillerpolicy (PolicyID Primary Key, accountID, BranchID, BIllerID, Enabled, ServiceCharge, MerchantCOmission,PLUCode)

Now I want to insert table tblbillerpolicy like this:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.tblbillerpolicy
      ( 

        AccountID                  ,
        BranchID                   ,
        BillerID                   ,
        Enabled                    ,
        ServiceCharge              ,
        MerchantComission          ,
        PLUCode        

      ) 

Select 142, 2171, 2, 'YES', 0.00, 3.50, 'NULL'

UNION ALL

Select 143, 2171, 2, 'YES', 0.00, 3.50, 'NULL'

UNION ALL

Select  143, 2171, 2, 'YES', 0.00, 3.50, 'NULL'

UNION ALL

Select  143, 2171, 2, 'YES', 0.00, 3.50, 'NULL'

where AccountID = accntid <-- for account
and BranchID = branchid <-- for branch
    and BillerID = billerid <-- for tblbillers
```

Now I really want to do is to insert this "ONLY" to tblbillerpolicy connected with the said tables (account,branch,biller).,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kristian Herman C.M.,

Are you want to insert the data (accountID 142, 143, etc) to the table with the condition: 
 
- the accountID (142, 143) is already in the table of account, 
 
- the branchID (2171) is already in the table of branch
 
- the billerID (2) is already in table of bill

If yes, please try the query bellow

```
INSERT INTO dbo.tblbillerpolicy
  ( 
    AccountID                  ,
    BranchID                   ,
    BillerID                   ,
    Enabled                    ,
    ServiceCharge              ,
    MerchantComission          ,
    PLUCode        
  ) 

select t.* from
(Select AccountID=142, BranchID=2171, BillerID=2, Enabled='YES', ServiceCharge=0.00,  MerchantComission=3.50, PLUCode='NULL'
UNION ALL
Select AccountID=143, BranchID=2171, BillerID=2, Enabled='YES', ServiceCharge=0.00, MerchantComission=3.50, PLUCode='NULL'
UNION ALL
Select  AccountID=143, BranchID=2171, BillerID=2, Enabled='YES', ServiceCharge=0.00, MerchantComission=3.50, PLUCode='NULL'
UNION ALL
Select  AccountID=143, BranchID=2171, BillerID=2, Enabled='YES', ServiceCharge=0.00, MerchantComission=3.50, PLUCode='NULL') t,
account a, branch b, tblbillers tb
where a.AccountID = t.accountID --for account
and b.BranchID = t.BranchID --for branch
and tb.BillerID = t.BillerID --for tblbillers
```

Comment: thanks Amy Widjaja .,it solves my problem for almost 2 days of googling the right answer.,:))